# Error in accuracy test

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, artificial-intelligence, probabilistic-programming

This is an update from my previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626968/dealing-with-class-imbalance-and-probability-calibration-in-my-image-recognition?noredirect=1#comment1169470_626968).

I'll put my Model Development code here for your reference:

```
# Splitting the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create a neural network model
model = Sequential()

# Convolutional layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Flatten layer
model.add(Flatten())

# Fully connected layers
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(37, activation='sigmoid'))  # 37 output nodes for 37 labels

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Print model summary
model.summary()

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print(f'Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy * 100:.2f}%')

# Save the trained model
model.save('my_model.keras')
```

My test accuracy is currently low, and I'm seeking guidance to improve my model's performance. Any code examples or detailed explanations would be appreciated.